# Deserialization not working across projects

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am encountering a problem with Json.NET (version 6.0.5) that leaves me a bit puzzled.

One of my classes that gets to be serialized looks something like this:

```
[JsonConstructor]
public MyContainerClass(IEnumerable<AbstractBaseClass> myDerivedUnitClasses)
{
    if (myDerivedUnitClasses == null)
    {
        Units = ImmutableHashSet.Create<object>();
    }
    else
    {
        Units = myDerivedUnitClasses.ToImmutableHashSet();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<AbstractBaseClass> Units { get; private set; }
```

Using `Json.Convert` with `TypeNameHandling` set to `TypeNameHandling.Auto` serializes this without problems. The serialized JSON includes the expected `$type`-qualifier for the property: `` "System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[[AbstractBaseClass, MyLibrary]], System.Collections.Immutable" ``

I got one project in my Solution where I serialize the data structure and another one where I deserialize it using `Json.Convert` (deserialization also using automatic type name handling). Deserialization fails with this error: `` Error resolving type specified in JSON System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[[AbstractBaseClass, MyLibrary]], System.Collections.Immutable ``

Using the source of Json.NET I traced the error back to the `DefaultSerializationBinder` calling `assembly.GetType(string name)` and getting `null` as result.

So far so bad. Here comes the part that leaves me especially puzzled right now: When I deserialize the JSON in the same code block where I serialize my data structure everything works perfectly fine (using the same code that I use in the other project).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try adding reference to the assembly for immutable collections to the project where you deserialize your data.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an assembly binding problem regarding the assembly containing `AbstractBaseClass` in the one project. I used `fuslogvw.exe` of the Visual Studio Tools while debugging to check for errors and noted that the directories that were searched were not the ones I was expecting and did not contain the assembly file.

My solution was to subscribe to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`-event prior to deserialization and then manually load the assembly from the correct path via `Assembly.LoadFrom` in the event handler.